# Entitytype has no key defined during view creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a view for the following Login controller under the model below. But during scaffolding I am getting an error as you see in the screen shot. How can I solve it?

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Error picture:

[image: pic]

[image: pic2]

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class UserLogin
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email ID required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email ID required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember Me")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model appears to be a view model (not your data model) in which case it should be in a separate folder (say ViewModels), not your Models folder so that its not associated with EF

Comment: namespace Test.ViewModel
{
} i have created it in this location but problem still same

Comment: The error means that your trying to associated this model with EF (and there is no `[Key]` attribute so EF cannot create the corresponding table in your database)!

Comment: You cannot enter anything in the _Data context class_ dropdown